# define a new route alias in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel. I'm using laravel 5.8 . I define a new route name called`signin` in `routes/web.php` and call it in my controller to redirect to this page. but laravel throw an exception with the error `"Method Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::signin does not exist`

```
 //.../routes/web.php
 Route::get('/registration', 'Mycontrollers@index')->name('signin');

//in Mycontroller.php
//some code
public function index(){

 //some code
 return redirect()->signin();
}
```

but if I used `return redirect()->route('signin');` it works fine

Comment: Where do you see the code `redirect()->signin();`?

Comment: `return redirect()->route('signin'); ` is the correct way to redirect from controller..

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what named routes are

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is correct, the [Redirector](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html) class does not contain a function `signin()`.

If you want to redirect to another route, you have to either use the route name (as in your working example), or the full class with its namespace. For example:

```
return redirect()->action('Mycontrollers@index');
```

You could also redirect directly to the path using `to()`:

```
return redirect()->to('/registration');
```

Comment: I see it in a laracast video, section 18. and it works fine. but when I try to use it as laracast uses, it gives that error

Comment: Can you add a link to this section or a screenshot of what their code looks like?

Comment: it's a video tutorial.![see it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9y3esw91mneaubs/route.png?dl=0)